# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer un JSON en PHP?

Tags: php, json, jsonarray

Estoy enviando un JSON a PHP para posteriormente subir los datos de este JSON a mi base de datos. El JSON que tengo es este:

```json
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "1234",
    "levels": {
        "[Nombre_ejemplo,0000]": {
            "[Nombre 1]": {
                "parametro1": "10",
                "parametro2": "10"
            },
            "[Nombre 2]": {
                "Checkbox": true,
                "parametro1": "10",
                "parametro2": "10"
            },
            "[Nombre 3]": {
                "parametro1": "10",
                "parametro2": "10"
            }
        },
        "[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]": {
            "[Nombre 1]": {
                "parametro1": "10",
                "parametro2": "10"
            },
            "[Nombre 2]": {
                "Checkbox": true,
                "parametro1": "10",
                "parametro2": "10"
            },
            "[Nombre 3]": {
                "Checkbox": true,
                "parametro1": "10",
                "parametro2": "10"
            },
            "[Nombre 4]": {
                "parametro1": "10",
                "parametro2": "10"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quiero recorrer el JSON en la parte de `levels`, y recorrer también a sus hijos. 
Lo que tengo ahora mismo en mi PHP es:

```php
$json = json_decode($_POST["json"]);
$levels=$json->levels;
print(count($levels));
```

Pero no me devuelve nada, me salta este error:

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Pero uso `var_dump($levels)`, sí que me devuelve todo el contenido de la parte de `levels` e incluso me pone un `(2)` al lado del nombre, indicándome que tiene dos hijos.

Mi versión de PHP es la `7.4.29`.

Un saludo y muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Ese json esta lleno de errores de sintaxis y otras cosas... mira de arreglarlo primero en https://jsonlint.com/. Aparte de eso, el **count** ya no actua sobre objetos, para conseguir contar sus elementos debes convertir a array, por ejemplo así: `print(count((array) $levels));`

Comment: Como dice @masterguru, el problema no está tanto en el código PHP como en el propio JSON: ids duplicados, comas antes de cerrar llaves, etc. Y si quieres convertir directamente el JSON a array asociativo, haz `json_decode($_POST["json"],true)` (con ese segundo parámetro).

Comment: Perdonad, que el JSON que he puesto es un ejemplo simplificado, tiene muchos mas hijos, el original me lo valida, no tiene IDs repetidos y no tienen errores de sintaxis, con la solucion que me ha propuesto @masterguru he logrado que me lo cuente pero no  se como acceder  a los hijos en el for.

Comment: Pon ese "for" que intentas en la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte a corregirlo. Seguramente lo mejor, para no ir liandola con mezclas de arrays y objetos entre padres e hijos, será lo que ha propuesto @VFG de convertirlo directamente todo a array y así será más facil de recorrer con un foreach o parecidos.

Comment: De todas formas, tienes un level con id `[Nombre,0000]` y después otro con el mismo `[Nombre,0000]`

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias. Para ello tan solo debes pulsar sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para agregar/modificar lo que sea necesario o te estemos pidiendo que pongas.

Comment: Esos dos ID son distintos el nombre seria distinto y el numero correspondería con el ID de cada uno que también va a ser distinto.  Ahora me lo convierte a un array con el código de @VFG , si pongo `print_r($json["levels"]);`  si que lo imprime pero cuando pongo `print_r($json["levels"][0]);` no lo imprime y yo necesito acceder a los  elementos sin saber sus nombres.

Comment: No te lo imprime porque contiene un array asociativo seguramente. Para acceder a alguno de sus registros determinado por su posición prueba con `print_r($json["levels"][array_keys($json["levels"])[0]]);` a ver si cuela

Comment: Como dice @masterguru, puedes obtener el `array_keys($json['levels'])`, meterlas en un array y después recorrer `$json['levels']`. Aunque después del `json_decode` yo metería lo de levels en un array directamente para que quede todo más claro. Si quieres acceder a un elemento directamente, sería, por ejemplo, `$json['levels']["[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]"]`. Cuidado con esos corchetes que forman parte del índice/clave, porque despistan.

Comment: Casi cuela @masterguru, con `print_r (array_keys($json["levels"])[0]);` me imprime solo el nombre pero no el contenido. Pero creo que con esto ya me funciona, guardo el nombre y en vez de hacerlo por el índice lo hago con el nombre. `$nombre=array_keys($json["levels"])[0];
print_r($json["levels"][$nombre]);` Muchas gracias a los dos, @VFG y @masterguru A ver si lo consigo ahora

Comment: Si te fijas eso no es lo que yo te habia sugerido, por eso solo sacas el nombre. Copia y pega mi código correctamente y obtendrás el resultado esperado: `print_r($json["levels"][array_keys($json["levels"])[0]]);`

Comment: Cierto @masterguru, no lo había copiado correctamente, ahora si que lo imprime bien. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Miguel He agregado una respuesta completa, la cual puedes verificar y si responde a tu pregunta marcar como aceptada para que no quede pendiente eternamente de respuesta. Si miras [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo cuando son correctas, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Basándonos en los comentarios de la pregunta, la solución final ha sido esta:

```php
$json = json_decode($_POST["json"], true);
print_r($json["levels"][array_keys($json["levels"])[0]]);
```

donde la primera línea convierte a array todo el json y lo almacena en la variable **$json** (gracias a @VFG por su aporte sobre el parámetro **true** de la función [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)).

Y en la segunda línea, para conseguir apuntar a un dato concreto basado en su posición en lugar de su clave, que puede ser desconocida, (en este caso dentro del **array asociativo** contenido en `$json["levels"]`), hemos usado [arrays_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php), que nos genera un nuevo array indexado.

Gracias a esto podemos sacar la clave basada en la posición, por ejemplo: `array_keys($json["levels"])[0]` nos devuelve **la clave** del primer *array asociativo* contenido en `$json["levels"]`.  Por lo tanto, al ponerlo todo junto, nos sale así para apuntar al contenido del primer array:

```php
$json["levels"][array_keys($json["levels"])[0]] // = $json["levels"]["[Nombre_ejemplo,0000]"]
```

Desconozco la practicidad de este método para el OP, pues solo permite extraer un registro cada vez, pero funciona, aunque cabe decir que lo habitual es simplemente recorrer el array con un foreach() para conseguir sacarlos todos o ir realizando operaciones sobre ellos, y esto podría ser así:

```php
foreach($json["levels"] as $clave=>$array_datos) {
    echo $clave."\n";
    print_r($array_datos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` devuelve unos objetos muy peculiares, dependiendo de la cadena Json enviada y los parámetros propios de la función. Al obtener valores la recomendación es *amoldar (cast)* apropiadamente. En este caso te devuelve un objeto que no implementa la interfaz *Countable*, pero si lo amoldas a un arreglo, éste si implementa dicha interfaz.

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['json']);
print( count((array)$json->levels) );
foreach( $json->levels as $nom1 => $val1 )
    foreach( $val1 as $nom2 => $val2 )
        foreach( $val2 as $par => $val )
            echo implode( '|', array($nom1,$nom2,$par,$val) ).PHP_EOL;
```

Resultado:

```
2
[Nombre_ejemplo,0000]|[Nombre 1]|parametro1|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0000]|[Nombre 1]|parametro2|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0000]|[Nombre 2]|Checkbox|1
[Nombre_ejemplo,0000]|[Nombre 2]|parametro1|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0000]|[Nombre 2]|parametro2|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0000]|[Nombre 3]|parametro1|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0000]|[Nombre 3]|parametro2|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 1]|parametro1|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 1]|parametro2|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 2]|Checkbox|1
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 2]|parametro1|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 2]|parametro2|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 3]|Checkbox|1
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 3]|parametro1|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 3]|parametro2|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 4]|parametro1|10
[Nombre_ejemplo,0001]|[Nombre 4]|parametro2|10
```